# Jenor chapter style

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

Is it possible to get the `Jenor` chapter style available with the `memoir` documentclass in the `scrreprt` documentclass (**Koma-script**)?

Here is a link to [`Jenor` style](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf#page36).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible; here's one possible solution (some vertical skips might require fine tuning):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor,fix-cm}

\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterheadstartvskip{\vskip50pt}

\newcommand\chaptitlefont{%
  \fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{db}%
  \fontshape{n}\fontsize{25}{35}\selectfont\raggedleft}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}%
  \fontsize{1in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}

\renewcommand\chapterheadendvskip{\par\vskip2mm\hrule\vskip40pt}

\renewcommand*{\@@makechapterhead}[1]{\chapterheadstartvskip
  {%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \if@chapterprefix
      \let\@tempa\raggedsection
    \else
      \let\@tempa\@hangfrom
    \fi
    \@tempa{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
          \if@chapterprefix
            \expandafter\size@chapterprefix
          \else
            \expandafter\size@chapter
          \fi
          \if@chapterprefix
            \size@chapterprefix{}\endgraf\nobreak\vskip.5\baselineskip
          \fi
      \fi
    }%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont #1}}
& \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
\end{tabularx}%
 \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip
}%
}
\renewcommand*{\@@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
  \chapterheadstartvskip%
  {\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \raggedsection \interlinepenalty \@M 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}%
{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont #1}%
\vphantom{\raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont 1}}}
\end{tabularx}%
\par}%
  \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test numbered chapter with a really long title}
\lipsum[3]
\chapter*{A test unnumbered chapter with a really long title}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Images of a numbered and an unnumbered chapter:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seems to work here : no line separator and text starts on the same line as the title. Here is my preamble http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2940

Comment: @s__C Of course it's not working; you added the lines `\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-40pt}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{1cm}}` so you suppressed the horizontal line. If you want to change the spacing, do so changing the values for `\vskip` inside the refefinitions for `\chapterheadstartvskip` and `\chapterheadendvskip` that are inside *my* code. By the way, some of your packages are causing conflicts; you need to load `amsmath` before `kmath`.

Comment: Ok now it's perfect. Thanks for your help Gonzalo.

Comment: @s__C You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.