# How to fix the chapter title and number using libertine font?

Tags: fonts, chapters, libertine

I came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69081/jenor-chapter-style) chapter style and borrowed the code (see MWE below).

The original code was using the font `pbk`; I want to use the `libertine` instead, since it is the font used throughout the thesis.

When I use the `libertine` the title font becomes thin, I want it to be thicker like the one by `pbk` or similar or:

*How to make chapter title and number look nicer using libertine?*

**MWE Code**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor,fix-cm}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{RGB}{150,20,0}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterheadstartvskip{\vskip50pt}

\newcommand\chaptitlefont{%
  \fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{b}%
  \fontshape{n}\fontsize{25}{35}\selectfont\raggedright}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{bd}\fontshape{n}%
  \fontsize{1in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}

\renewcommand\chapterheadendvskip{\par\vskip2mm\hrule\vskip40pt}

\renewcommand*{\@@makechapterhead}[1]{\chapterheadstartvskip
  {%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \if@chapterprefix
      \let\@tempa\raggedsection
    \else
      \let\@tempa\@hangfrom
    \fi
    \@tempa{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
          \if@chapterprefix
            \expandafter\size@chapterprefix
          \else
            \expandafter\size@chapter
          \fi
          \if@chapterprefix
            \size@chapterprefix{}\endgraf\nobreak\vskip.5\baselineskip
          \fi
      \fi
    }%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont #1}}
& \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
\end{tabularx}%
 \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip
}%
}
\renewcommand*{\@@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
  \chapterheadstartvskip%
  {\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \raggedsection \interlinepenalty \@M 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}%
{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont #1}%
\vphantom{\raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont 1}}}
\end{tabularx}%
\par}%
  \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Materials \& Methods}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae}
\end{document}
```

**Output: PBK**
[image]

**Output: Libertine**
[image]

Comment: It is hidden in the `libertine` documentation, that there is a `\libertineSB` command, for **semibold** usage of the font, so insert in your `\chaptitlefont` command. See page 4 of documentation, to be found here http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/libertine/doc/libertine.pdf

Comment: I get no difference in the chapter title with or without `libertine`

Comment: @egreg I updated the code and output, can you try now pls?

Comment: No change. What TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, but it is not clear for me in the manual how to apply `\libertineSB` in the MWE, any help?

Comment: @egreg, TexLive2013 - XeLaTeX.

Comment: `\usepackage[type1]{libertine}` is necessary to let it work with `xelatex`,see the mentioned manual on page **3**

Comment: @doctorate: Please consider egreg's answer rather than mine, he made some efforts and provides a better solution.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I have one problem, I need `fontspec` in preamble for a certain monotype font, and this will abolish the bold affect of  libertineSB, once I remove `fontspec`, the effect re-appear, any idea?

Comment: I never used `fontspec` so far, because I do not run `xelatex` and its capabilities for Open Type fonts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The family name you should use is *not* `libertine`. Just change `\fontfamily{pbk}` into `\rmfamily` (this is because, by default, `scrbook` applies `\sffamily` to chapter titles).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor,fix-cm}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{RGB}{150,20,0}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterheadstartvskip{\vskip50pt}

\newcommand\chaptitlefont{%
  \rmfamily\fontseries{b}%
  \fontshape{n}\fontsize{25}{35}\selectfont\raggedright}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \rmfamily\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}%
  \fontsize{1in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}

\renewcommand\chapterheadendvskip{\par\vskip2mm\hrule\vskip40pt}

\renewcommand*{\@@makechapterhead}[1]{\chapterheadstartvskip
  {%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \if@chapterprefix
      \let\@tempa\raggedsection
    \else
      \let\@tempa\@hangfrom
    \fi
    \@tempa{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
          \if@chapterprefix
            \expandafter\size@chapterprefix
          \else
            \expandafter\size@chapter
          \fi
          \if@chapterprefix
            \size@chapterprefix{}\endgraf\nobreak\vskip.5\baselineskip
          \fi
      \fi
    }%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont #1}}
& \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
\end{tabularx}%
 \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip
}%
}
\renewcommand*{\@@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
  \chapterheadstartvskip%
  {\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \raggedsection \interlinepenalty \@M 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}%
{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont #1}%
\vphantom{\raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont 1}}}
\end{tabularx}%
\par}%
  \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Materials \& Methods}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @doctorate,@egreg: I can confirm egreg's solution, the bold effect is definitely better than on my solution.

Answer (score 2):

I inserted `\libertineSB` after in the `\chaptitlefont` before `\fontshape`, but after it is the same.

However, I use `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% For XeLaTeX use 
%\usepackage[type1]{libertine} instead
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor,fix-cm}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{RGB}{150,20,0}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterheadstartvskip{\vskip50pt}

\newcommand\chaptitlefont{%
  \fontfamily{libertine}\fontseries{b}%
  \libertineSB% for example in here%%%%
  \fontshape{sc}\fontsize{25}{35}\selectfont\raggedright}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \fontfamily{libertine}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{sc}%
  \fontsize{1.0in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}

\renewcommand\chapterheadendvskip{\par\vskip2mm\hrule\vskip40pt}

\renewcommand*{\@@makechapterhead}[1]{\chapterheadstartvskip
  {%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \if@chapterprefix
      \let\@tempa\raggedsection
    \else
      \let\@tempa\@hangfrom
    \fi
    \@tempa{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
          \if@chapterprefix
            \expandafter\size@chapterprefix
          \else
            \expandafter\size@chapter
          \fi
          \if@chapterprefix
            \size@chapterprefix{}\endgraf\nobreak\vskip.5\baselineskip
          \fi
      \fi
    }%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont #1}}
& \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
\end{tabularx}%
 \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip
}%
}
\renewcommand*{\@@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
  \chapterheadstartvskip%
  {\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \raggedsection \interlinepenalty \@M 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}%
{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont #1}%
\vphantom{\raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont 1}}}
\end{tabularx}%
\par}%
  \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Materials \& Methods}
\lipsum[2]
\chapter*{Curriculum Vitae}
\end{document}
```

[image]